# Monitor Command prompt from Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, command-prompt

I am trying to open command prompt on my Emulator. I need to open ABC folder of my computer from Emulator. Is it possible to open command prompt on Emulator or Android device and monitor my PC?

Or is there any other way to browse computer data on Android device or Emulator?
[Here](http://kathabuzz.com/android-terminal-adb-shell-commands/) I found one image which open command prompt on mobile.  But I don't understand how it works.

Comment: The emulator thinks it's a phone. Why would a phone be able to browse a particular PC?

Comment: @HansKesting: i need to browse PC when it's connected by USB.... this is possible by Bluetooth and Wi-Fi but i need by USB Cable...

Answer (score 0):

you can't open a terminal into an Emulator . but you can access your emulator from respective OS's terminal or command prompt.

To run `Terminal` on Phone you can use `Android Terminal Emulator` app available on `Google Play Market`.

you can find it [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)